# A conjecture concerning convergence of a kind of recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Along the thread given here, [Find the limit of a recursive sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002365/find-the-limit-of-a-recursive-sequence#), I am very curious about the limit of the recursive sequence
defined by
\begin{gather*}
 u_0>0, \quad u_1>0,\quad  u_{n+2}=\sqrt{u_{n+1}}+\sqrt{u_n},\quad  \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.
\end{gather*}

After some trial and error, I guess that there may be a generalization. I put my conjecture below. Let $k\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{0,1\}.$ Assume 
\begin{align*}
 u_0>0,\quad  u_1>0, \quad  u_{n+2}=\sqrt[k]{u_{n+1}}+\sqrt[k]{u_{n}},\quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.
\end{align*} 
Then we may have
\begin{gather*}
 \lim_{n\to\infty} u_n=\sqrt[k-1]{2^k}=2^{\frac{k}{k-1}}.
\end{gather*}

Is my conjecture true or false?  Can you prove or disprove it?

Comment: @BrainMScott, Sorry, I have trouble in editing, for there is always pop-up, saying "Mathematics Stack Exchange requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load." Therefore, I have to type very quickly, and so made some errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** the sequence converges, the limit must satisfy $u = \sqrt[k]{u} + \sqrt[k]{u}$, giving indeed $u = 2 ^ {\frac{k}{k-1}}$. Just prove that it does converge.